# Mule CXF module is missing UrlUtilities

Tags: java, mule, cxf

when trying to access WSDL of my SOAP services I am getting exception NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/transport/http/UrlUtilities.

Mule CXF module is being used in my code to expose SOAP services. Current mule version is 3.3.5(I know it's old..:)) and CXF version 2.7.x. I noticed that missing class (UrlUtilties) was present prior to cxf-rt-core version 2.6.0. 
Wondering if this class is no more required by cxf 2.7 and my mule version is way behind or I am mixing to un-supported version of libraries, if that is the case then does any one know what is the max version of CXF I can go with mule 3.3.5. 
My mule service configuration is very similar to what is mentioned in article "https://dzone.com/articles/web-services-with-mule-cxf-and"

Here is my mule service configuration. "myMuleCXFServletConnector" is a servlet connector

```
<service name="com.myorg.myservice">
<inbound>
    <inbound-endpoint address="servlet://myService" connector-ref="myMuleCXFServletConnector">
<cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.myorg.MyService"/>
</inbound-endpoint>
</inbound>

<component>
<spring-object bean="mycomp.services.myservice"/>
</component>
</service>
```

I am suspecting either I missing some library or using incorrect version, I am hoping that some of you may have some suggestions to fix this issue. Your input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't find a Mule 3.3.5 release. Is that the correct version?

Comment: the version is mule-core-3.3.5sr

Comment: I'm asking because there is no tag for 3.3.5 in the source code. The nearest release is 3.3.4 that uses CXF 2.5.9 <cxfVersion>2.5.9</cxfVersion> I'm not sure how your installation got CXF 2.7. Did you override the version provided?